# Default banking account with which money is received within PayPal

Tags: paypal

If I have a few bank accounts associated with PayPal, and I receive a payment, then which account will it go into?

*Does it transfer to a default account or must I manually transfer it to one of my choice?*

Also, how can I even view the two banking accounts (e.g. last 4 digits) and which is default?

I cannot even see the details in PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when receiving payments in Paypal, they are first stored in Paypal itself. The money stays there until you transfer it to your desired bank account.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Paypal account.

On the My Account tab, the last menu choice of Profile... mouse over it, and choose Add or Edit bank account.

One of the accounts there should be marked as "Primary".  This would be your default account.  When you transfer money from Paypal into one of your accounts, you choose at the time of the transfer, however, you are offered the Primary account as the first choice.

Comment: I see under profile..my money, the accounts.

Comment: so primary account is only for when receiving money it comes up as first choice?

Comment: It's the primary account for anything that requires your bank account.  When you want to pay via direct withdrawal from one of your accounts, the primary is the first choice as well.  The account you designate as primary is the account you see as the one that should be considered first for everything.

Comment: When I make a payment in ebay it asks me which credit/debit card to use, and doesn't say a thing about either of my bank accounts especially not my primary bank account.

Comment: Asking you which credit/debt card to use, is not asking you which bank account you want to withdraw the money from directly.  Yes, I know that you can enter a bank card as a credit card... that bank card taking the money out of your account.  What I'm talking about, is those times when paying via paypal gives you the initial choice of an eCheck, or paying via credit card.  If you choose to pay by credit card, then you aren't going to see anything regarding your primary bank account.